# Ansible Generate CSV report from Multiple Facts

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I hope this finds you all well.

I´m struggling to generate a CSV from multiple facts corresponding to the same hosts.

More specifically, I have the following facts:

```
   ntp_status:
    host01: Clock is synchronized
    host02: Clock is synchronized
    host03: Clock is not synchronized

   ping_status:
    host01: Ping success
    host02: Ping not success
    host03: Ping success
```

The idea is to have a report in a CSV file report.csv, hence I would expect to generate with Jinja something like the following:

```
   host, ntp_status, ping_status
   host01, Clock is synchronized, Ping success
   host02, Clock is synchronized, Ping not success
   host03, Clock is not synchronized, Ping success
```

I hope you can help me with this. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          host, ntp_status, ping_status
          {% for i in _csv %}
          {{ i }}
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        _hosts: "{{ ntp_status.keys()|list }}"
        _ntp: "{{ ntp_status.values()|list }}"
        _ping: "{{ ping_status.values()|list }}"
        _csv: "{{ _hosts|zip(_ntp)|zip(_ping)|
                  map('flatten')|
                  map('join', ', ')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    host, ntp_status, ping_status
    host01, Clock is synchronized, Ping success
    host02, Clock is synchronized, Ping not success
    host03, Clock is not synchronized, Ping success
```

---

The next option is to create the structure in the template. The task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          host, ntp_status, ping_status
          {% for i in _hosts %}
          {{ i }}, {{ ntp_status[i] }}, {{ ping_status[i] }}
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        _hosts: "{{ ntp_status.keys()|list }}"
```

---

Put the template into a file, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat report.csv.j2 
host, ntp_status, ping_status
{% for i in _hosts %}
{{ i }}, {{ ntp_status[i] }}, {{ ping_status[i] }}
{% endfor %}
```

and create the report

```yaml
    - template:
        src: report.csv.j2
        dest: report.csv
      vars:
        _hosts: "{{ ntp_status.keys()|list }}"
```

gives

```sh
shell> cat report.csv
host, ntp_status, ping_status
host01, Clock is synchronized, Ping success
host02, Clock is synchronized, Ping not success
host03, Clock is not synchronized, Ping success
```